# CSV does not download after I clicked the button,

Tags: json, reactjs, export-to-csv

Whenever I click the button, it only displays the logs and did not started the download of the csv file I'm generating. I dont know what approach shall I use. Im just new to react and javascript.

here's my code ,

```js
getReport = async function(){
     
      const jsonUrl = 'https://us-central1-connected-nursing-home-2.cloudfunctions.net/retrieveEHR';
      const res = await fetch(jsonUrl);
      const json = await res.json();
      console.log(json);
     
      const data = json.map(row=> ({
        firstName : row.firstName,
        lastName : row.lastName,
        birthDate : row.birthdate,


      }));
       const download = function(data){
      const blob = new Blob([data, {type: 'text/csv'}]);
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      // link.setAttribute('hidden','');
      link.setAttribute('href',url);
      link.setAttribute('download','data.csv');
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);

      const csvData = objectToCsv(data);
      console.log(csvData);
   }
     

      const objectToCsv = function(data){
        const csvRows = [];
        const headers = Object.keys(data[0]);
        csvRows.push(headers.join(','));
        console.log(csvRows)

        for (const row of data){
         const values = headers.map(header => {
         const escaped = (''+row[header]).replace(/"/g,'\\"');
         return `"${escaped}"`;
          });
            csvRows.push(values.join(','));

          };
            return csvRows.join('\n')
          
        }    
      }
```

and here is my button

```html
<Button className="ehr-export-btn" 
        name="Export to PDF"        
        onClick={this.getReport}>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFilePdf} size="lg" /></Button>
```

Comment: Can you please provide minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi sir, i cant create a minimal reproducible example, I'm just gonna ask, how can I pass the 'csvData' value to another variable outside the 'getReport' function?